# Do .frm files represent the entirety of a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, cut-and-paste

So let's say I copy /var/lib/mysql and save it somewhere else, then uninstall/reinstall MySQL and put the original /var/lib/mysql back where it was. Will I have all of my databases without any trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, just `.frm` files are not enough.
2. However, If you **stop your MySQL server** and copy everything under `/var/lib/mysql`, including `ibdata1`, `ib_logfile0`, `ib_logfile1`, and everything in subdirectories under `/var/lib/mysql` (*.frm, *.ibd files), and later on restore these files to some other server, using the same version of MySQL and same configuration (/etc/my.cnf or similar), then you'll be fine.
3. There are better ways to keep backup or transfer data between servers. See `mysqlhotcopy`, `mysqldump`, etc.